# Hosted SharePoint privacy

Tags: security, sharepoint, hosted-exchange

I was wondering if there is anyway to have a hosted SharePoint that is not accessible by the hosting company.

I've spoken to 2 vendors so far and one can access the site but has a audit list and the other claims that they can only access it with the administrator credentials

Because our company is almost entirely telecommuting we need somewhere to host data such as employee information (name bdate social government clearance) b.

Is this something i should be suspiciousness of? or am i just being paranoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a standard like PCI would be the best bet, this compliance regulation is not only for credit cards when looking at a host because it goes beyond in demonstrating a provide that follows the proper precautions and security to host sensitive data such as financial records, credit cards, medical files, etc.

It is understandable for paranoia when having such sensitive data and your business critical information.  Ultimately your provider should never be looking at your content however if you need more reassurance a host that practices compliance regulations might be better fitted.

If you need some recommendations feel free to reach out to me.

Comment: I need recommendations

Comment: shoot me an email noneil@gmail.com